# How to get data for BeautifulSoup Xml Parser

Tags: beautifulsoup, xml-parsing

I'm trying to parse an XML file with BeautifulSoup. In all tutorials on the net, the content of the xml is given like

```
xml = "<doc><tag1>Contents 1<tag2>Contents 2<tag1>Contents 3"
soup = BeautifulStoneSoup(xml)
```

but I want to give only xml file's path. In mechanize one can use get_data() method but it only works for html files. Any sugestions ?

Answer (score 0):

The BeautifulSoup [documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#Parsing%20a%20Document) says that:

"A Beautiful Soup constructor takes an XML or HTML document in the form of a string (or an open file-like object). It parses the document and creates a corresponding data structure in memory."

In the formulation of your question, you use `BeautifulStoneSoup`, and allthough the online documentation uses strings, the docstring for the constructor reveals that:

"The Soup object is initialized as the 'root tag', and the provided markup (which can be a string or a file-like object) is fed into the underlying parser."